# firestore security rules for server side requests

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i'm flutter-fire user since last fall

> Note: The server client libraries bypass all Cloud Firestore Security
> Rules and instead authenticate through Google Application Default
> Credentials. If you are using the server client libraries or the REST
> or RPC APIs, make sure to set up Identity and Access Management (IAM)
> for Cloud Firestore.

Comment above is from [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields) by firebase team. It sounds like 'server client libraries' or apis in the comment mean the requests from outside of my mobile apps, and they gon bypassing cloud firestore security rules. But when i tried the same get request with Postman with just same request from the one in my app without permission, the response in Postman console was fine, which means that there came a permission denied error.

So, here comes my question. I hope to know what types of requests exactly are equivalent to these 'server client libraries' or 'the REST or RPC APIs' mentioned in the official reference that bypass all the security rules. Postman is exactly 'the REST', and firebase worked as i wanted(produced permission denial) perfectly in this case. So there must be some specific types that firebase team actually intended to refer to be careful of.

I understand that firebase-admin sdk is one of the possible server side libraries, but exactly the same permission or auth procedures should be required when we tried to access firebase admin sdk which can control firebase data above the security rules just like firebase team commented. So the question is focusing on possible attackers' solutions to maliciously manipulate our firebase without the proper security procedures.

Hope some firebase gurus would give cool answers for the question with awesome knowledge and experiences! Thank you in advance [:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As their name indicate, the server client libraries are to be used from a server or from a "trusted environment" like Cloud Functions.

When interacting from your server (or your trusted environment) with the Firebase server APIs you don't authenticate as you would authenticate from a client application. Instead of using user accounts created through the Firebase Authentication service (e.g. email/password account) your server should use [Google service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production). More details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) in the Firebase doc.

Note that for Cloud Functions, you initialize the Admin SDK with no parameters. In this case, the SDK uses Google Application Default Credentials (exactly as indicated in the documentation excerpt you mentioned in your question).

So, when your server (or your Cloud Function) interacts with the Firebase server APIs, since it is authenticated with a service account, the requests bypass all Cloud Firestore Security Rules. In other words, if you want to implement some check to allow/forbid specific operations based on specific parameters/values, you have to implement them in your code.

---

For the REST API, it is the same. The REST API can be used from a client application (a web app, a Flutter app, ...) or from a server.

Depending if it is a client or a server, you should authenticate by using a Firebase Authentication ID token or a service account (together with Google Identity OAuth 2.0 token), as explained in detail in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api).

So, when you make a request to the API with Postman without permission, as you did, the API detects that there is no Google Identity OAuth 2.0 token or Firebase Authentication ID token associated with the request and then the Security Rules are enforced => you get a "permission denied error".

---

In conclusion, if you correctly define your Security Rules you should not encounter any problem with "attackers maliciously manipulating" your database.

Note however that Security Rules only based on `auth != null` may not be sufficient to protect your data, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67061657/3371862).

Comment: Thank you sir! The answer is cool enough for me to init my tiny code base [: i think it would be better to post another question if i got any issues after doing some experiments with myself. Super cool answer for now! [: